# how about an installer to setup complicated developer environment?

Tags: svn, installation, environment

Our developer environment setup tends to have a lot of moving parts with a lot of steps. Every day when we need to do an svn update, there are a number of things we need to do and sometimes when it fails to work, we need to rollback everything, including the svn updates, so we can go on working locally.

What would be a good way to provide a developer environment updater ? I am looking at some installer software etc., but want something easy to customize. I develop on windows am not familiar with C# etc., I maybe able to use powershell or perl or some such.

Are there are already plugin type libraries for this ? Not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal installer is probably what you want. Something simple like [nullsoft installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Uninstalls/reverts are a lot of pain to do correctly. If possible virtualize dev boxes and make a snapshot before deploying an update.

Comment: would I be able to call svn update from it and also run ant build ?